# Excel Addin not appearing on some machines

Tags: vsto, excel-2007, excel-addins

I am having some difficulties with installing an Excel addin at my client. I have created an installer for the addin using the instructions at http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-msi-installation.aspx, and it has been successful for the majority of users. The installer was run as an admin and this seemed to work ok. However for a small proportion of users the installation was unsuccessful - the registry entries are created but the addin does not load when Excel starts and does not appear in the addins list. Trying to add it manually from the installation folder gives an error that the addin is not valid.

To complicate matters slightly, the client uses both Vista and XP (although all installations of Excel are 2007). None of the XP machines have installed the addin successfully, whereas most (but not all) of the Vista machines have been successful.

Has anybody had any experience of this, or might be able to point out where I am going wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

There were changes to various user profile paths between XP and VISTA. If you've hardwired any paths like \Users\username\Application Data, etc, you may not be installing things quite right under XP, where the path would typically be \Documents and settings\username\Application Data.

Finally, if an addin isn't loading, about the only causes are
1) the reg entries pointing to it (or to the MANIFEST in the case of VSTO) either aren't there or aren't right.
2) the addin has some prerequisite or dependency that you've missed, and since it's not there, the addin loader is just failing to load the addin.

For 1), just check the reg entries for all the right values, then add a msgbox or some logging in your addin to verify that it is, indeed, at least being initially loaded by Excel.

For 2) I'd read up on the Fusion Loaded Viewer and use that. Fusion is the .net "loader" service, and it can be setup to log all sorts of detailed info about where it's looking for preqs, which one are found where, and which can't be located.

Details here

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: Regarding your first point, the application is being installed to "C:/Program Files/<Manufacturer>/<Addin Name>/", so I doubt there is an issue here. I will have a look into whether there were any registry changes that occured though, thanks for pointing this out. I am pretty certain that the application isn't even attempting to load, there is no error associated with loading, no sign of the addin in the excel addins list (enabled or disabled), it is literally as though Excel has no idea it should even be trying to load it, which lead me to look at the registry. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: and what was the reason why it was not there in the end?